# Read File meta-data in Notes

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I have a Notes database with photos as attachments.
These photos have GPS information as meta data in the file like long / lat / ...
Basically I want to retrieve the data you get when right clicking on a file in windows and open the properties of the file (details tab).

Is there a way to retrieve this information in Notes. Preferably in LotusScript, but Java is also an option. 
Windows functions are no option, since the OS can be anything.
However, it does not matter if the code runs on the domino server or the notes client.

Comment: You can use Java to read metadata from an image (with the ImageIO classes)

Comment: Hi Per, you put me on the right track. With ImageIO, it seems hard to get the GPS data; but I found this class javaxt.io.Image, that has a function getGPSCoordinate( ). Thanks
http://www.javaxt.com/documentation/?jar=javaxt-core&package=javaxt.io&class=Image